# Django understanding uniq constraint on nested models

Tags: django, django-models

Having the following model

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    

class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person = models.ForeignKeyField(to=Position)
    department = models.ForeignKeyField(to=Department)
```

I would like to assure that a person is unique in one department (means can only have one position in one department). My aproach would be to use a constraint on position,
but I cannot figure out

1. What Q statement to use for condition.

```
class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person = models.ForeignKeyField(to=Position)
    department = models.ForeignKeyField(to=Department)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = UniqueConstraint(fields=['person'], condition=Q(???))
```

I would expect there to be something like `Q(<all_departments>)` which i could not find

**EDIT**: What if there is a more complex relationship:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    models.ForeignKey(to=Company)


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    

class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person = models.ForeignKeyField(to=Position)
    department = models.ForeignKeyField(to=Department)
```

and a person should only have one position for a company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is just UniqueConstraint with [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#fields) listed

```
UniqueConstraint(fields=['person', 'department'], name='unique_department_person')
```

This ensures that only one combination of same person and department exists in database

Comment: So and if I Had also an FK-relationship from department to Company and I would like to assure a person is unique for a company? (sorry, tried a minimal example -.- did not work out ...)